# Highlight Current Menu Item Using Prototype JS

Tags: magento, menu, prototypejs

The challenge is to set current menu item as active in magento, which uses Prototype JS and not JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="mainmenu">
<li><a href="{{store url=''}}">home</a></li>
<li><a id="menuItem" href="{{store url='our-cakes'}}">Our Cakes</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url='about-us'}}">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url='Outlets'}}">Outlets</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url='franchise'}}">Franchise</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url='contacts'}}">contact us</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
$(mainmenu).childElements().each(function(e){
var h = e.down('a').readAttribute('href');
if(h == window.location){
e.addClassName("current");
}
});
});
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refinement of that method. Note that depending on the browser, the href of a link and the window.location.href may have a substring match, but not a full match, because of the rest of the URL which the browser provides from context. Just `==` is not going to make it.

```
var here = $$('#mainmenu a').sortBy(function(a){
  return a.href.length;
}).reverse().find(function(a){
  return window.location.href.include(a.href);
});
if(here) here.up().addClassName('current');
```

Also, this is looking for the longest match first, so you don't get all of the menu items highlighted on the home link `/`.